# Connecting to SSH with Fingerprint of the SSH Key

Tags: ssh

Hello! I have problem with connecting to remote host. I forgot ssh password but I have Fingerprint of the SSH Key. Is it possible to connect with using just fingerprint?

Comment: Fingerprint of who's SSH key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The fingerprint of the machine is just used to verify you're connecting the machine your think you're connecting to.  It is public information used to avoid [Man in the Middle Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM) on your SSH session.